# Add Group in Model - Django

Tags: django

I had created a group name "company" with some permissions. I want to add a group while creating a model.

models.py

```
class ComapnyUser(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    myshowroom=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    slug=models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True,unique=True,null=True)
    contact=models.IntegerField()
    address=models.TextField(blank=False,default='')

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug=slugify(self.username)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: Consider adding the source code of all the relevant models, for more precise anwers.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.utils.text import slugify

class ComapnyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,)
    myshowroom=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    slug=models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True,unique=True,null=True,blank=True)
    contact=models.IntegerField()
    address=models.TextField(blank=False,default='')

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug=slugify(self.user.username)
        #get the group by its name
        company_group = Group.objects.get(name='company') 
        # user_set is the reverse relation with Group
        company_group.user_set.add(self.user.id) 

        super().save(*args,**kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```